# I2C read from registers with Arduino

Tags: arduino, byte, i2c

I'm having some trouble understanding I2C. This is my first time using the protocol. The documentation says the following

[image: Screenshot of the documentation.]

I just don't know if I am supposed to write to a read register and the two bytes are 0x00 and 0x01, or use Wire.request to request two bytes.

I have read registers from 0-20 and several write registers however I'm only interested in the read registers.

Any help would be much appreciated and please ask any questions you might have.

Thanks,

Peter

**EDIT**

```
#include <Wire.h>

void setup() {
// put your setup code here, to run once:
Wire.begin();
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
// put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
int k = readRegister(0x08, 0x06);
Serial.println(k);
delay(500);
}

uint16_t readRegister(uint8_t i2cAddr, uint8_t regAddr) {

// I2C write sequence to address the given read register
Wire.beginTransmission(i2cAddr); // Module address
Wire.write(regAddr);             // Register Address
Wire.write(0);                   // Command Data = dummy zeroes
Wire.write(0);
Wire.write(regAddr);             // Checksum
Wire.endTransmission();          // Finish I2C write sequence

// I2C read sequence to actually get the register value
Wire.requestFrom(i2cAddr, 3);
uint16_t regVal = Wire.read();
regVal <<= 8;
regVal |= Wire.read();
if (Wire.read() == (((regVal >> 8) + regVal) & 0xFF)) {
    return regVal; // Checksum OK
}
return 0xFFFF;     // Checksum error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the only way to say which register you want to read is to complete an I2C write sequence using that register's address. Probably the "Command Data" you use in the write sequence will be irrelevant if you use the address of a read register.

So it would become something like this:

```
uint16_t readRegister(uint8_t i2cAddr, uint8_t regAddr) {

    // I2C write sequence to address the given read register
    Wire.beginTransmission(i2cAddr); // Module address
    Wire.write(regAddr);             // Register Address
    Wire.write(0);                   // Command Data = dummy zeroes
    Wire.write(0);
    Wire.write(-regAddr);            // Checksum
    Wire.endTransmission();          // Finish I2C write sequence

    // I2C read sequence to actually get the register value
    Wire.requestFrom(i2cAddr, 3);
    uint16_t regVal = Wire.read();
    regVal <<= 8;
    regVal |= Wire.read();
    if ((Wire.read() + regVal >> 8 + regVal & 0xFF) == 0) {
        return regVal; // Checksum OK
    }
    return 0xFFFF;     // Checksum error
}
```

It is usual in many chips to access subsequent register addresses incrementally by just issuing new read sequences. This way you could do a bulk or multi-byte read. However I'm not sure that's the case here, so you might need to do the write sequence every time.

Comment: Hi Luis, thank you for your answer! I waited to get back from school and then I wrote the arduino program with your code. I just edited my question with the code. However it didn't work, all I got was 0 in the serial monitor.

Comment: The checksum was incorrect, that could be the problem. I have edited it above. You can always (re)check your I2C address and connections too.

Comment: It didn't work :( thanks for your help so far. I got the same zeroes back. The only thing I can think of now is shifting ghe 7 bit register address over and adding a read bit on the end, which is I hope what it means by "sending the 7 bit address with a 1 to indicate a read command.

Comment: If you are getting zeroes, then it's probably sending something with a correct checksum in the read sequence, otherwise you should get 0xFFFF. I had a quick look at the full Serial Link document, but unfortunately the protocol specs are not very clear. What communication mode are you using? Do you have an oscilloscope or a logic analyzer, by any chance?

Comment: How do you select the communication mode actually? I couldn't find that in the docs.

Comment: Yes,  the checksum works because all the values are zeroes anyway. I am currently using I2C without the passthrough mode. I don't have a logic analyser or an oscilloscope. I select the communication mode by connecting it to a link device which allows me to change the settings. Right now I have chosen I2C at 100khz and device address 0x08.